# How can I compile nodejs with a different version of V8 and is it smart?

Tags: node.js

There was a bug in V8 that was making my application take up a lot more memory than it had to, but its been fixed recently.  Therefore, I would like to compile nodejs with a newer version of v8.  How can I do this And is it smart?

I noticed that the version of v8 that the stable nodejs uses is quite old (from the end of 2012!)  I think v8 has improved a lot since then so there must be some reason nodejs comes with an older version of v8.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying this, I would just use the latest node v0.11 releases, which have a much newer v8, and are very close to being declared stable and blessed as v0.12. While technically possible to at least attempt a different v8 change, I believe your chances of success at getting all of node core plus whatever npm modules you need working are pretty slim and it will take some time if you aren't already an expert in this domain. Plus you are circumventing a good community process. If you have a legit bug with memory usage, and it's not already fixed in the latest v0.11 release, file it. node core pays attention and responds to these things.

Comment: Good to know.  Its not hard to circumvent the memory problem so I guess I'll just circumvent it for now.  Its not a big enough bug that I think someone would spend time to backport a fix, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407911.